# how to direct customer to PayPal for payment

Tags: php, html

I have developed a shopping cart. The customer choose items and 'display.htm' page shows the item name, total quantities and total payment that he has to pay. So i want to know that when a customer clicks on ' Click Here For Payment' button , how to make him to pay by PayPal.

```
display.html:

<body>
<body onLoad="getDoc()">
<div id="display"> </div>
</body>

display.php:


     <?php
                     $xml = new DOMDocument;
                     $xml->load("cart.xml");
                     $book = $xml->getElementsByTagName("book"); 
                     echo "<table border=1><tr><th>Title</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total Price</th></tr>";   
                    $total_pay=0;
                      foreach($book as $node) 
                     { 
                    $title = $node->getElementsByTagName("title");
                    $title = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;  
                    $quantity = $node->getElementsByTagName("quantity");
                    $quantity = $quantity->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $totalprice = $node->getElementsByTagName("totalprice");
                    $totalprice = $totalprice->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $total_pay=$total_pay+$totalprice;
                    echo" <tr><td>{$title}</td><td>{$quantity}</td><td>{$totalprice}</td></tr>";
                    }
                   echo "</table>";
                   echo "<br />";
                   echo "Your total payment is: $total_pay  <br/>";

                   echo "<form><input type='button' name='submit'  value='Click Here to Proceed For Payment' onClick='window.location.href=   '/></form>";

                ?>
```

Comment: are you going to be using the Paypal Api?...If not, you can simply add a hyperlink to a button to direct them to a donation page(if they are donating).

Comment: Ok, Have you read the documentation? There are some code examples that are very useful.

Comment: I have not used Paypal before. Where is the documentation?

Comment: Look here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home_US

Comment: and here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro

Comment: @Elite Gamer thanks its very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to www.paypal.com and review the Web Pro Payment API. They supply sufficient PHP API documentation including the HTML specific to your Paypal account for a proper checkout.

Comment: where is that option (Web Pro Payment API)

Comment: Login to paypal -> Merchant Services -> Website Payments Pro API (under the 'for developers' header near the bottom right).